# Is a holding pattern always counter-clockwise?

Tags: airspace, traffic-pattern, holding, air-traffic-management

Is a holding pattern always counter-clockwise? Or is it dependent upon the controlling airspace?

Comment: Right turns are standard for ICAO. In PANS-OPS ([Doc 8168](http://code7700.com/pdfs/icao_doc_8168_vol2.pdf)), Procedures for Air Navigation Services, section 4, chapter 1: "If no operational considerations prevail, **right turns** holding patterns should be established. For **left turns** holding patterns, the corresponding entry and holding procedures are symmetrical with respect to the inbound holding track"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The holding pattern can have any inbound course, and any direction. The holding pattern course/direction, depends on departing/arriving traffic, and many other factors. London Heathrow has a clockwise and counterclockwise hold on the fix LYDD. 
Thanks to Pondlife for pointing LYDD out!

[image]

Comment: A better example from your image might be the holds at LYDD: one uses right turns and the other uses left turns.

Comment: You could use both patterns, do a figure-8 and not get dizzy!  :)